# PHP errors in WordPress foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a custom theme and looping all post types with checkboxes, but I'm also getting a couple of PHP errors:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array (
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
), 
    'objects'
);
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="woo_custom_options[post_types][]" value="<?php echo $post_type->name; ?>" <?php if ($post_types && in_array($post_type->name, $woocustomoptions['post_types'])) echo 'checked';?> />: <?php echo $post_type->label; ?>
<?php
}
```

The errors I am getting are:

> Notice: Undefined index: post_types

and

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

...both for the same line number.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Apparently `$woocustomoptions['post_types']` doesn't exist. What does `var_dump($woocustomoptions);` return?

Comment: When I var_dump I don't see post_types. But if I tick a checkbox and save my settings, all the errors go away. The errors only appear when no checkboxes have been ticked and settings saved.

Comment: Then the key 'post_types' isn't set when no checkboxes are ticked which explains the warning message you're seeing. Your code needs to handle that as well (eg. `if ( isset($woocustomoptions['post_types']) ) { /* Your code here * } else { /* No checkboxes ticked, do something else */ }`)

Comment: Thanks. That led me to try this which seems to work:

`$post_types = isset($woocustomoptions['post_types']) ? $woocustomoptions['post_types'] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this into the foreach makes the errors go away:

`$post_types = isset($woocustomoptions['post_types']) ? $woocustomoptions['post_types'] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the variable **$post_types** is empty, try wrapping with a validation.

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array (
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
),
    'objects'
);
if (isset($post_types)) {
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="woo_custom_options[post_types][]"
               value="<?php echo $post_type->name; ?>" <?php if ($post_types && in_array($post_type->name, $woocustomoptions['post_types'])) echo 'checked'; ?> />: <?php echo $post_type->label; ?>
        <?php
    }
}
```